# Obtain the value of a variable in another class?

Tags: java

I have a problem getting the variables to pass to another class, because it keeps passing me a blank variable.

I want to get the value of `id` from the method `search()` and transfer it to `class foo` inside the method `total`...

Class `Boo` :

```
//method inside of class boo

public void search(){

try{

        String id = searchBox.getText();
        String idNum="";

        rs = stat.executeQuery("Select * from students where idNum='"+id+"'");

        while(rs.next()){

            idNum = rs.getString("idNum");

        }//while

            Members members = new Members();
            setVisible(false);

            members.setIdVal(id);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }

}//search
```

Class `Foo`:

```
// methods inside Foo
public void total(){

    System.out.println("Get: "+getIdVal());

    try{

    rs2 = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM paymentRecord where idNum ='"+getIdVal()+"';");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Total Error: "+e);
    }//

}//total

public void setIdVal(String val){

    this.val = val;

}//get the id

public String getIdVal(){

    //System.out.println("Inputted ID:" + val);
    return this.val;

}//get the id
```

Comment: Try a smaller example - to see how to do this you do not need all the reading from SQL see http://sscce.org

Comment: You question making no sense as of now. Please cut down the code and post SSCCE soon.

Comment: there you have it, hope you understand now, forgive me, cause its mhy first time using stackoverflow.com..

Comment: Your `members` object dies with the `search()` method. Place `Members members = new Members();` in a wider scope outside of the method so that you always have a members object to reference.

Comment: what do you mean by that? how can place it into wider scope?by putting it globally?

Comment: what do you mean by "blank variable"?

Comment: blank i mean nothing.. if `id = "11000811";` then if i get `id` it gives me `id="";`

Answer (score 0):

`getIdVal()` is a method of a `Foo` class, but it should be a method of `Boo` class.

```
class Boo {
   private String id;
   public void search(){
        // ...
        this.id = searchBox.getText(); 
        // ...
   }

   public int getIdVal() {
      return this.id
   }
}
```

While the `Foo` class:

```
Class Foo {
   public string Total(){
      Boo boo = new Boo();
      System.out.println(boo.getIdVal()); // will print the value from id searched in search() method
   }
}
```

You have to choose where to call `search()` method.

Comment: can i `getIdVal()` without calling `boo`? is it possible? cause they both have their own `psvm` and `JFrame`..

Comment: hey?i tried what you said but it return me `null` instead the value of `id`.. btw i call `search()` in `class Boo`, when the button search button is click it will call the method search..